# QuarkusTest always failing when using PanacheMock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Hi I'M currently trying to define a test for a service which should do operations on a specific entity.
The problem is that it always fails before running the tests.

Project setup:
Environment

- macOS 10.16
- Java 11
  Project
- Build tool: Gradle

Dependencies (Gradle)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-liquibase'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator'
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'

    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-h2'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-panache-mock'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:kotlin-extensions'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
}
```

Test code:

```java
@QuarkusTest
public class CategoryServiceImplTest
{
    @Inject
    CategoryServiceImpl categoryService;

    @Test
    void should_get_page_of_3_categories()
    {
        // given
        PanacheMock.mock(Category.class);
        final List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            categories.add(ApplicationTestUtils.generateCategory());
        }
        when(Category.find(any(), Sort.by("name"))).thenReturn(mock(PanacheQuery.class));
        when(Category.count()).thenReturn(30L);

        // when
        final ListModel<Category> result = categoryService.getList(3, 0);

        // then
        assertEquals(result.getListInfo().getLengthTotal(), categories.size());
    }
}
```

when I try to run this test it just returns this in the console:

```
> Task :test
Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following classes for reflection as they are not in the Jandex index:%n%s%nConsider adding them to the index either by creating a Jandex index for your dependency via the Maven plugin, an empty META-INF/beans.xml or quarkus.index-dependency properties.");.
> Task :test FAILED

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:526)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeEach(QuarkusTestExtension.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:161)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:160)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:415)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.run(StartupActionImpl.java:196)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:232)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:504)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:537)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:189)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:293)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.getDefaultValidatorDescriptors(ConstraintHelper.java:1150)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.lambda$getAllValidatorDescriptors$0(ConstraintHelper.java:869)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper$ValidatorDescriptorMap.computeIfAbsent(ConstraintHelper.java:1189)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper$ValidatorDescriptorMap.access$100(ConstraintHelper.java:1179)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.getAllValidatorDescriptors(ConstraintHelper.java:869)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.descriptor.ConstraintDescriptorImpl.<init>(ConstraintDescriptorImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.descriptor.ConstraintDescriptorImpl.<init>(ConstraintDescriptorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.buildConstraintDescriptor(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.lambda$findConstraintAnnotations$0(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:542)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findConstraintAnnotations(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:543)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findConstraints(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findConstraints(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:461)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findPropertyMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getFieldMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.PredefinedScopeBeanMetaDataManager.getBeanConfigurationForHierarchy(PredefinedScopeBeanMetaDataManager.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.PredefinedScopeBeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(PredefinedScopeBeanMetaDataManager.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.PredefinedScopeBeanMetaDataManager.<init>(PredefinedScopeBeanMetaDataManager.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.PredefinedScopeValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(PredefinedScopeValidatorFactoryImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.validator.PredefinedScopeHibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(PredefinedScopeHibernateValidator.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:430)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.HibernateValidatorRecorder$1.created(HibernateValidatorRecorder.java:130)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.initBeanContainer(ArcRecorder.java:106)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources1649676420.deploy_0(ArcProcessor$generateResources1649676420.zig:496)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources1649676420.deploy(ArcProcessor$generateResources1649676420.zig:40)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:240)
    ... 66 more
```